# C pointer to function with cast

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have a this function which needs a Two Dimensional Integer Array:

```
void Add_Binary_To_Matrix(int (*qrMatrix)[21], int *binPtr,
        int x, int y, int count, int skipper, int direction)
```

And this array which is a one dimensional pointer array but I add memory to each row (which also makes it a two dimensional integer array right?):

```
int *qrCopy[currentVersion->height];
for (int i = 0; i < currentVersion->height; i++) 
    qrCopy[i] = malloc(currentVersion->height * sizeof(int));
```

So I've tried passing it a bunch of ways but none of them work:

```
Add_Binary_To_Matrix((int *)qrCopy, binPtr, 20, 20, 0, 0, 1);
Add_Binary_To_Matrix(qrCopy, binPtr, 20, 20, 0, 0, 1);
Add_Binary_To_Matrix(&((int *)qrCopy[0]), binPtr, 20, 20, 0, 0, 1);
```

but passing it like that doesn't seem to work so my question is how can I pass this array to the function?

Comment: You should describe the context in which this occurs—what does the function do, what form do you have the data in before you call this function, and can you change this function or can you only change how you call it? The primary problem here is not the parameter and argument types, which are easily changed, but how the data is laid out in memory. Does the parameter `qrMatrix` point to just one array of 21 `int` or to possibly more than one array, laid out consecutively in memory?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to pass the array to the function.

The type of `int (*qrMatrix)[21]` is a pointer to "21-element array of integers".

`qrCopy` is an array of pointers, so this cannnot be passed.

How to set the argument: Create an array and obtain pointer to that.

```
int array[21];
Add_Binary_To_Matrix(&array, binPtr, 20, 20, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: The question is not clear, but the use of `int *qrCopy[currentVersion->height];` suggests the array has more than one row. Then `int array[21];` should be `int array[currentVersion->height][21];` and the argument `&array` should be `array`.